# HMAC Authentication with Supertest

Tags: node.js, hmacsha1, supertest

I need to intercept the `supertest` request to sign my requests as our endpoints all require to be signed.

We follow a similar HMAC Signing process as AWS, I can generate the signature fine. But I see no easy way to intercept the request to iterate through the http request headers etc...

Ideally I thought I could do:

```
it("return 401 if auth header is signed wrong", function (done) {
        api
          .post('/v1/users/sessions')
          .use(function(request, response){
            hmac.signRequest(request, wrongSecret, wrongAccess);
          })
          .expect(401)
          .end(function (err, res) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            done();
          });
```

On the `Super-Agent` project there appears to be `.use(fn)` method. Which has the `req,res` passed through as params to the callback.

But that seems to not apply to the `supertest` agent.

Am I missing something or is there another simple way to do this?